# MSSQL Cascade Delete Two columns with FK to one Table

Tags: sql-server, merge, foreign-keys, relationship, cascade

Hi I have a simple Table A and B,

```
Table A 
int Id NOT NULL

Table B
int Id NOT NULL
int A1 NULL (FK to Table A.Id)
int A2 NULL (FK to Table A.Id)
```

What I would like to do is to delete record from Table B when related record (on A1, A2 or both) has been deleted.

I've created on DELETE action Cascade on A1 relationship and it works perfectly but when I'm trying to set up on DELETE action Cascade on A2 relationship I got:

> 'A' table saved successfully 'B' table
>   - Unable to create relationship 'FK_B_A2'.   Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_B_A2' on table 'B' may cause cycles or multiple cascade
>   paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify
>   other FOREIGN KEY constraints. Could not create constraint or index.
>   See previous errors.

I don't understand why this can't be set up? I simple want to be able use SQL MERGE on table A (and when something is deleted I want to delete related records in table B or the merge fails).

Comment: What is relationship between tables? Table B `A1 ` and `A2` columns are related with Table A `Id` column ?

Comment: Yes, I will update my post, columns A1 and A2 has FK to table A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can solve this by

1) Set Cascade Delete on A1

2) Instead of Setting Cascade Delete on A2 Create **Trigger** like so:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [DELETE_B]
   ON dbo.[A]
   INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS 
BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;
 DELETE FROM [B] WHERE A2 IN (SELECT Id FROM DELETED)
 DELETE FROM [A] WHERE Id IN (SELECT Id FROM DELETED)
END
```

Comment: any other solution (without trigger)?